# Android SDK installation (adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030)

Tags: android, eclipse-adt, android-sdk-manager

I have Win7-64 laptop, installed JDK, Eclise is working. I am failing to install the Android SDK. I downloaded 'adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030' from developer.android. When I used SDK Manager, i could select required installation components and it shows as complete. However, I dont see anything in the 'All Programs'. I also dont see any plugin (that I was supposed to see) in the Eclipse as well. So I gather I am missing some step. Can anyone help. Pl see![][1]

Answer (score 1):

Your downloaded sdk files may not shown in `All Programs` as they are not executable nor meaningless to be clickable.

Sometimes many folks got a problem to point out exact SDK path, so more than one SDK binaries are downloaded. I think your eclipse cannot find sdk path properly.

To find out where the SDK path is, it displays in SDK Manager.

[image]

Then, you can set the path in Eclipse `Eclipse->Window->Preferences-> select Android from left hand menu`. Check `SDK Location` has same path; [see screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33450932/361100).

FYI, as downloaded files are just a bunch of *binaries* used only for Android development, you can copy the whole `android-sdk` folder to other place.

I personally recommend to change the directory to `C:\Android` or `C:\User\<me>\Documents\Android-sdk` as default directory is in `C:\Users\<me>\AppData\Local` hidden folder.

Answer (score 0):

The ADT bundle includes an Eclipse executable fully configured with the Android SDK tools.  It does not add a plugin to an existing Eclipse install.  To launch ADT/Eclipse goto .   Search for eclipse.exe within that directory.  This is the executable you need to launch.

On my Mac, the Eclipse executable is in `/Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse.`  Just a guess, but on Windows, the path will probably look something like `adt-bundle-windows-x86/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/windows/eclipse.exe`

Comment: <ADT Path>\eclipse\eclipse.exe

Answer (score 0):

I would personally suggest to **use Android Studio** 2.1 for easy install of plugins as whenever there is an update to any platform tools or build tools they are readily available and the dependency injection is far better with the build tools such as Gradle which are bundled with the Android Studio .
[Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Android adt is plugin to use Android SDK in Eclipse IDE**. You have `SDK` you have `Eclipse` now you need to install adt plugin in eclipse to use your SDK.

You can refer Android developers for plugin installation

https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Download

For "I dont see anything in the 'All Programs' I also dont see any plugin" part you will not see any extra program installed in your system as adt is extension of eclipse. When you will have adt in place you should be able to see Android option in eclipse preferences. You should also be see Android APplication option while creating new project.