# Set existing android sdk path to eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, path

I was previously using eclipse Helios for android apps development but now I have switched to eclipse kepler. So what I want now is to use my existing android sdk to be used in eclipse kepler. 
I have read many thread but they say go to window --> Perspective --> select Android.
The problem is I can not see android option in a list of tabs.
So pls tell me how can I set path of android sdk folder in eclipse kepler.

Answer (score 7):

First, you need to [install ADT in Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html).

That generally sets everything up, but if not, the setting is in Window -> Preferences -> Android -> SDK Location.

Answer (score 3):

I tried this in Eclipse Kepler and below worked for me:

**Eclipse->Window->Preferences-> select Android from left hand menu->** There you should see option to set SDK path

**Check below screenshot:**

[image: Setting SDK Path Screenshot]